# iTunes-like Bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, itunes

I'm trying to make my bootstrap carousel look similar to the carousel type feature they have on iTunes.

My best guess would be some sort of jQuery to put 3 items under the same active div, but my current attempts have failed.

For reference; The attached image shows the iTunes slider.

This is **not** trying to make it look like Coverflow, which makes images 3d.

Alternatively, if it is a struggle with Bootstrap - I would love to look into other jQuery plugins that could help me achieve this effect.

Image: [iTunes Slider Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElhIj.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)..!

its touch enabled jQuery plugin that lets you create beautiful responsive carousel slider.
it has many variaties of carousel sliders and with a well structured documentation. 
as you wish try this [demo.](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html)

its kind of work like what you expect. goodluck .